# How can I get options of a chart in Spreadsheet that are objects? (like `titleTextStyle` or `vAxes`)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have data in a spreadsheet and on a separate sheet a chart based on that data. The chart has both left and right vertical axes. The min and max values of the axes are set to be automatic, meaning the scale of the axes adjust automatically based on the input data.

I need to get the actual min/max value of the axes with apps-script.

Seemingly I need to follow [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart#getoptions) and use the options listed [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart). For simple options like `title` it works, but not for options that are objects like `titleTextStyle` or even more so `vAxes`.

Here is the current code:

```js
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('some ID'); 
  var chartSheet = ss.getSheetByName('some name');  
  var chart = chartSheet.getCharts()[0];
  var optionsTitle = chart.getOptions().get('title'); // works fine, returns a string
  var optionsTTS = chart.getOptions().get('titleTextStyle{}'); // without {} give an access denies error, with {} returns null
  var optionsA = chart.getOptions().get('vAxes{}'); // without {} give an access denies error, with {} returns null
```

Any suggestions how to get these more complex options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameters for `hAxis` and `vAxis` are JSON. When it retrieves a parameter from it, it uses a key. For example, in order to retrieve the `color`, `fontSize` and `fontName` for `titleTextStyle` of `hAxis`, it uses as follows.

**Sample :**

```
var hAxis_titleTextStyle_color = chart.getOptions().get('hAxis.titleTextStyle.color')
var hAxis_titleTextStyle_fontSize = chart.getOptions().get('hAxis.titleTextStyle.fontSize')
var hAxis_titleTextStyle_fontName = chart.getOptions().get('hAxis.titleTextStyle.fontName')
```

**Note :**

Also `vAxis` can be retrieved by above. But now it cannot be done. `null` is returned. I confirmed just now. I have tried for this as follows.

1. I created a new chart by GAS, and retrieved `vAxis` by above script. It works fine.
2. I created manually a new chart on spreadsheet, and retrieved `vAxis`, It doesn't work. `null` is returned.
3. When I modified `vAxis` on the manually created chart by GAS, at the spreadsheet, `vAxis` of chart is not changed.
4. For the chart created at 3, when `vAxis` is retrieved by GAS, the modified parameters can be retrieved. But `vAxis` of the chart on spreadsheet is the condition before it is modified.

I think that this is a bug. Recently, chart builder was updated, so some bugs may be remained. I don't know whether this also occurs under the environment of other users.

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I meant. How can I retrieve `vAxes` (plural) that is supposed to return **both** left and right vertical axis properties (when it works)? ("This property can be either an object or an array" per the documentation linked above)

Comment: @B.No When titles for left and right are set, it uses ``.setOption('vAxes', [{title: "left title"},{title: "right title"}])``. So when they are retrieved, I think that it uses ``chart.getOptions().get('vAxes[0].title')`` and ``chart.getOptions().get('vAxes[1].title')``. But now I got ``null``. The bug that I said yesterday has not been modified yet. So it is considered that this may be also a bug. But I don't know. I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure how to reference the array/object option. I will report the bug to Google.